# Taking continuos input in an integer array

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to make a class for adding huge integers.
I have 2 arrays both of size 40 I wanted to know if there is any way I can take input with out doing the old school method:

```
for(int i=0;i<40;i++)
{
   std::cin >> arr[i];
}
```

In this way I have to take input 40 times. Is there a way to take input like we do in `cin.getline`?

Comment: 1. how do you want to handle the situation in which the input is shorter than 40? 2. how do you represent data in memory? array of integers? array of chars? 3. did you take 40 for the sake of an example or that's your largest supported size?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't get an array of integers directly, since there's no overload for this type. You'll have to either use third-party library for parsing or define an additional overload for `operator>>` and array. Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

template <int  N>
std::istream & operator>>(std::istream & is, std::array<int, N> a)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    is >> a[i];
  return is;
}

int main()
{
  std::array<int, 10> ar;
  std::cin >> ar;
  for(auto & e : ar)
    std::cout << e << ' ';
  return 0;
}
```